# form data is showing empty after append

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-data

```js
$('#submit2').click(e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form_data = new FormData();
  form_data.append('newKey1', 'newValue1');
  form_data.append('newKey2', 'newValue2');
  console.log("data after appended", form_data.get('newKey1'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="submit2">See form data in Console</button>
```

I want to add files in form data, but I am unable to append, so I tried to add key and values, and I am unable to append this in form data.

Comment: It seems working fine. the log message is "data after appended newValue1"

Comment: I have updated your code snippet so you can see your `FormData` is having values set. You can't `console.log` your `FormData` instance and expect to print the whole object.

Answer (score 2):

It's not empty you just can't access it like that try this:
console.log([...dataForm.entries()])

Answer (score 1):

Your `FormData` is fine, you just can't `console.log` it and expect to see the content.

This is how you would normally use your `FormData`:

```js
document.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: new FormData(event.target),
    }).then(function (response) {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        }
        return Promise.reject(response);
    }).then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.warn(error);
    });
});
```

If you want to log the object, you need to do something like this:

```
var serializeForm = function (form) {
    var obj = {};
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    for (var key of formData.keys()) {
        obj[key] = formData.get(key);
    }
    return obj;
};

serializeForm(formData)
```

Sources:

- [Developer Mozilla - Web API FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)
- [Serializing form data with the vanilla JS FormData() object](https://gomakethings.com/serializing-form-data-with-the-vanilla-js-formdata-object/)